# How to get all values of specific nested property in JS object

Tags: javascript, object

I can't seem to find an answer I'm satisfied with, so sorry if this question is a duplicate question, maybe I don't even know how to phrase what I want to achieve.

So anyway this is example code:

```
var characters = {
  hero: {
    name: 'player',
    hp: 100,
    moves: {
      attack1: {
        damage: 10
      },
      attack2: {
        damage: 20
      },
      attack3: {
        damage: 30
      }
    }
  }
}
```

What I want to do is write a selector for damage values to split them in half or do any other math on all of them at once. For now I've been checking different syntaxes with console log

```
console.log(characters.hero.moves[what here?].damage);
```

but I don't know what to do next, to get only integers, and edit them.
I already know * doesn't work to select all here. It's my first time using objects. Is it necessary to write a for function for example?
I don't want it to become array or anything as I saw some answers using them. I just want to get to those values and change them all at once to multiply, divide, increase or decrease them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//fixed error :D
var characters = {
  hero: {
    name: 'player',
    hp: 100,
    moves: {
      attack1: {
        damage: 10
      },
      attack2: {
        damage: 20
      },
      attack3: {
        damage: 30
      }
    }
  }
}

//the following function takes in ONE function as its argument
//this argument function is given a number(a damage number)
//the number the argument function returns become the new damage number
function editDmg(fn){
  var moves=characters.hero.moves
  Object.keys(moves)
  .forEach(a=>moves[a].damage=fn(moves[a].damage))
}

//example usage
editDmg(
  n=>n*2 //multiplies all dmg values by 2(you can do any math equation like n=>n_based_equation_here)
)
console.log(characters)
//second use to prove i've fixed it
editDmg(n=>n/2)
console.log("for a second time",characters)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you have an object (`moves`) that has other objects. You may **map** each value of the `moves` object to some nested value.

You may use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values) (which returns an array with all the values of the given object) and then [`Array.prototype.map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to do the mapping.

Something like:

```js
const characters = {
  hero: {
    name: 'player',
    hp: 100,
    moves: {
      attack1: {
        damage: 10
      },
      attack2: {
        damage: 20
      },
      attack3: {
        damage: 30
      }
    }
  }
};

const movesDamage = Object.values(characters.hero.moves)
  .map((move) => move.damage);
  
console.log(movesDamage); //=> [10, 20, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, your moves property would be an array, but, given the data you have (and assuming that every 'attackN' property is an object with a single property called damage, then:

```
var movesKeys = Object.keys(characters.hero.moves);

for (var key in movesKeys)
{
    var attackObject = characters.hero.moves[key];
    attackObject.damage = attackObject.damage * 2; // double the damage
}
```

Comment: This one doesn't seem to work. movesKeys displays only names "attack1" etc after checking in console, so I think thats why I'm getting  "damage of undefined" - its just not an object anymore, only name

Comment: That's correct.  if key = `attack1`, then the next line `var attackObject = characters.hero.moves[key]` will return the attack1 object, from where you can access `attackObject.damage`.

Answer (score 0):

To Sum all damage values:

```
characters.hero.moves.attack1.damage + characters.hero.moves.attack2.damage + characters.hero.moves.attack3.damage
```

If you dont know how many attaks the hero has use this:

```
var total_damage = 0;
Object.keys(characters.hero.moves).forEach(function(key) {
  total_damage += characters.hero.moves[key].damage;
});
console.log(total_damage);
```